I'm clueless when it comes to epoxy, how do I get the finish I want?
This is my first time on this forum, I tried to search for some questions similar to mine, but there aren't any, or I'm searching wrong (which is likely my issue, haha!).
I have made many live edge tables and barnwood tables myself, but have never used epoxy. I've always been happy with a non-perfect finish, and would get it sanded quite smooth then just cover with clear polyurethane. This time, I'm making a dining/kitchen table for a family member. She wants a dark colored live edge slab. I am either going to try to find nice piece of walnut, or use some other type of wood and put a dark brown stain on it. She says she does not care either way.
She also will homeschool her 3 kids at this table and therefore wants a very durable, smooth finish, as it will be used daily for a majority of the day. This is where my epoxy questions come in. It is quite overwhelming trying to research all this, so I hope my questions can be answered so I can learn a little!

Is it okay to put an epoxy over a stain (If I decide to go that route)?
What are the types of epoxy, and what type do I want that will be hard, durable, and look nice, but not too glossy of a finish?
How much would such epoxy cost?
Is there anything else I should be thinking about when going into this project?

Thanks!!

Hi, welcome to StackExchange & Woodworkinig. And thanks for searching the stack first! I don't think you missed anything, numerous Answers mention epoxy but we have few or no previous Qs that include finishing with it (except maybe CPES). However you're asking far too much; the form on SE is one query per Question. In addition it requires of askers that they do solid research to find answers for themselves before asking something here — in essence you should be asking about things that remain unclear after you've read all you can find, and there are now abundant epoxy resources online. [contd]

1st bullet you'll easily find answers for online but spoiler, yes. (I would highly recommend using waterbased dyes instead of an oil stain BTW, or a combo.) 3rd bullet is essentially unanswerable since it depends on what you choose to use, but in general you do want to be thinking expensive. 4th bullet, yes: not using epoxy! Epoxy is actually not a good standalone finish! As amazing as this sounds a lot of present-day epoxy projects are going to bite the builder's in the butt down the line. Not to bury the lead here, go with one of the finishes used commercially for finishing tabletops.

Now 2nd bullet, this is perilously close to a shopping question which are off topic for here. But I presume you've watched at least a few vids on river tables and other projects where they poured on epoxy? See all the sanding that is done to perfect surfaces after the epoxy has hardened sufficiently to proceed? Because of this the original gloss level becomes completely irrelevant, with the final finish being then determined solely by the nature of the sanding and buffing done. Hope these points help you get started on your research.

Yeah, points of cost are explicitly off-topic - prices vary too much by region and can change from day-to-day. I am confused, however, with what you're planning on doing with the epoxy. You say you want to stain the wood, but then you're going to coat the entire surface with epoxy? Any sort of colored epoxy would simply hide the stain, and if you're going to use a clear epoxy, I'd think going to with polyurethane would be far easier and less expensive. Why do you want epoxy as a surface coating, not a gap filler?

@FreeMan I used epoxy as a surface coating, they make special epoxy for table/bar tops that are great.  they are also self leveling.  the problem I see here is that being a natural edge top is where a LOT of extra work will be in doing a pour, since the 2 ways are make a damn or let it over flow and clean up.  both would be time prohibitive on a  natural edge table.

Huh... #TIL, @bowlturner.

@bowlturner I used clear epoxy on a natural edge bar top, and there were no particular difficulties with the edge vs. epoxy. It took a little attention to make sure it flowed over all parts of the edge. You definitely need plastic/drop cloths EVERYWHERE to catch all the overflow, with special care where they overlap. After the epoxy cured, the bottom of the edge needed a quick sanding to remove all the frozen drips.

@Rob, very cool.  I'd like to see pics of the finished product!

@bowlturner Slabs of white pine. Filled all the worm holes with orange-tinted epoxy (had to seal the back side on quite a few). Sanded the epoxy flat and did final sanding of the slabs. Then stained black. Then clear coat of epoxy. Turned out really nice. It is the bar in our nano brewery in New Hampshire. (our logo is orange and black, thus the choices of colors) At first I was bothered by how many worm holes there were, but when it was done, I was wishing there were way more! They add so much character.
